# Who is Eminem talking about in his song Lose Yourself?

Tags: rap

Who is Eminem talking about? About himself when he was young?

> He opens his mouth, but the words won't come out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The lyric is self-referencing; the character Jimmy Smith Jr. aka B-Rabbit that Eminem plays in the movie [8 Mile](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0298203/).

The line itself specifically refers to an event in the movie, where he takes part in a rap battle, but dries on stage & leaves embarrassed.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/8_Mile_(film)) says the movie 'contains autobiographical elements', but doesn't make clear which parts are & which are simply movie plot.

Comment: somega - shameless self-promotion [I don't make any money out of this, it's entirely for fun, so admins please forgive me;) - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SUFHXDZRo58 - "Imagine if Eminem's Lose Yourself had been done by an old bloke from Yorkshire…"

Comment: Good work, Tetsujin! It's great. And it's not an easy song. If you could get it to Eminem I swear he'd want to do a collaboration!